# Disable jQuery datepicker on mobile, input type="date"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, datepicker

I have a small problem with detection and disable jQuery date picker in mobile phones.
I have this JavaScript code (enable datepicker):

```
$( "input[type='date']" ).datepicker();
```

And CSS (hide Chrome native datepicker):

```
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{ display: none;}
input[type="date"]::-webkit-input-placeholder{ visibility: hidden !important;}
```

On the desktop, this works fine, but on mobiles, two date pickers are displaying. 
I want hide jQuery Datapicker, but avoid scripts like Modernizr.

Maybe someone can help me with some CSS or little JavaScript?

example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title> Datepicker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<style>
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{ display: none;}
input[type="date"]::-webkit-input-placeholder{ visibility: hidden !important;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <input type="date" />
    </form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
 $(function() { 
  $( "input[type='date']" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            firstDay: 1 }) 
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I place this code here: http://www.stack.puniserv.pl/

I want to resign from jQuery date picker in mobile.

Comment: Provide a complete working example the demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Dekel I update my post. In mobile two datepickers appear. I want hide jQuery datepicker.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS `@media` querys to hide elements on mobile viewports. Adjust breaking point to desired, `767px` is used as example, so when viewport is above that it should be visible and when below hidden. Make sure you set the querys at the end of your CSS file.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
   input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { 
      display: none; 
   }
   input[type="date"]::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
      visibility: hidden !important;
   } 
}
```